# If statement vs if else

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been playing with titanic data and tried a simple if statement below, without "else":

```
if passenger.gender == 'female':
    predict[passenger_numberId] = 1
predict[passenger_numberId] = 0
```

My code runs fine and I get an accuracy of 63%. When I modify the statement with "if else", the accuracy increases but I do not understand why adding else is different to my simple statement above that follows the instructions per link: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html:

```
if passenger.gender == 'female':
   predict[passenger_numberId] = 1
else:
    predict[passenger_numberId] = 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Without else the result is always 0, because the bottom line always executes. What you're missing is knowledge about if/else statements

Comment: Not for long, thank you for your response @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `if` test, one of the following two things happens:

- you set `predict[passenger_numberId]` to `1` *first*, then **immediately**, set it to `0`.
- you set `predict[passenger_numberId]` to `0`.

So, without an `else` statement, you **always** set `predict[passenger_numberId]` to `0`, and it doesn't actually matter what the outcome of the `passenger.gender == 'female'` test is.

By using `else` you **only** set `predict[passenger_numberId]` to `0` when the `if` test didn't pass, and to `1` when it does pass.

In other words, by using `else` your code now takes one of two paths, and the outcome differs based on the choice of paths. Without the `else`, the value is always set to `0`, regardless of the test.

Answer (score 0):

It always sets predict to 0 because there's no else. The accuracy should tell you that 37% are females.